# Change System Custom Data

Tags: visual-studio

I use to program in VB6 and started the Visual Studio VB thing for past 6 months or so. I need to find a way to change the users PC system date format to custom format using VS2010
Without asking the user to go through the control panel

I had a look at the following code but it does not permantly set the system date format

Dim en As New CultureInfo("en-US")
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = en

```
    ' Creates a DateTime for the local time.
    Dim dt As New DateTime(2001, 7, 13, 4, 0, 0)

    ' Converts the local DateTime to the UTC time.
    Dim utcdt As DateTime = dt.ToUniversalTime()

    ' Defines a custom string format to display the DateTime.
    ' zzz specifies the full time zone offset.
    Dim format As [String] = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:sszzz"

    ' Converts the local time to a string
    ' using the custom format string and display.
    Dim str As [String] = dt.ToString(format)
```